# Bootstrap responsive menu based on height and width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, responsive

In Bootstrap all breakpoints are based on width. It is possible to base on height or toegether?
I explain my problem: I have a web site with a sidebar menu on the left for desktop or large width like this

[image]

By default Bootstrap behaviour changes menu in hamburgher when width dimension is less than 767 px like this
[image]

And that's is great!
I want another condition... I want to get the hamburgher menu always when the HEIGHT is less than 600px like this

[image]

So I want check width and height ...

```
if (Height < 600px) {displays hamburgher}
if (Height > 600px && Width > 767px) {display sidemenu}  
if (Height > 600px && Width < 767px) {display hamburgher}
```

How it is possible to get this?
Thanks

I post the code:
HTML

```
<header class="nav-down responsive-nav hidden-lg hidden-md ">
        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="sidebar-navigation  hidden-xs">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#" data-target="">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#" data-target="">
                        MENU 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#" data-target="">
                        MENU 2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#" data-target="">
                        MENU 3
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#" data-target="">
                        MENU 4
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
.responsive-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9), rgba(0,69,139,0.8));
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-toggle span {
  background-color: #dedede;
}
.sidebar-navigation {
  width: 22.5%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #00458b;
  z-index: 10;
}
.sidebar-navigation nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
}
.sidebar-navigation ul {
  margin-left: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-navigation li{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.sidebar-navigation nav a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sidebar-navigation nav a:hover, nav .active-section {
  color: #3fd2c7;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .responsive-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .responsive-nav {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, try to **rewrite your question**...
 I think that everybody can understand what you mean just by the code at the bottom of the question.

These images are doing more harm then good. Try to post some of your **code** so we can show you how to do it on that code.

Also I think this can be done with JavaScript, where you specify your window `width` and `height`and based on that you will be able to change this **displayed menu**.

Comment: I am not clear about your question. Did you mean you want to always display hamburger menu bar as long as the height is less than 600 px, even the width is 1600 px, for example?! In general, you can have rules for min-width and min-height: `@media screen and (min-height: 600px) { ... }`. I am just not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Yes it's exact. The problem is that there are 2 controls responsive.... one by me with @media screen and.. and the second inside bootstrap. So i need to combinate them like a if instruction